# how to show the current value after delete the dynamic row in ionic with angular js

Tags: angularjs

### While I delete the dynamic row it should recollect the cost feild value and show the exact value in green color button using angular js.Please find the image.

```
<div style="background-color:#FFFFFF;min-height:color:#FFFFFF">
  <div style="background-color:#FFFFFF;height:40px;" > </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-75">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Material Name" ng-model="thingstodo[0].mname">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Rs" ng-maxlength="4" ng-model="thingstodo[0].cost">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-75">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Material Name" ng-model="thingstodo[1].mname">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Rs" ng-maxlength="4" ng-model="thingstodo[1].cost">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-75">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Material Name" ng-model="thingstodo[2].mname">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Rs" ng-maxlength="4" ng-model="thingstodo[2].cost">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-75">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Material Name" ng-model="thingstodo[3].mname">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Rs" ng-maxlength="4" ng-model="thingstodo[3].cost">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-75">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Material Name" ng-model="thingstodo[4].mname">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Rs" ng-maxlength="4" ng-model="thingstodo[4].cost">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" data-ng-repeat="rowContent in rows" show-delete="false" can-swipe="true">
    <div class="col col-50">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Material Name" ng-model="thingstodo[rowContent].mname">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Rs" ng-maxlength="4" ng-model="thingstodo[rowContent].cost">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col" align="center" style="padding-top:15px">
      <i class="font25 icon ion-ios-trash" ng-click="deleteRow($index,rowContent)"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" align="center"> </div>
    <div class="col col-75" align="right"><button class="button icon ion-ios-plus-outline" ng-click="addRow()"></button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-75">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" readonly value="Labour Charges">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Rs" ng-maxlength="4" ng-model="thingstodo_additional.labourcost">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-75">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" readonly value="Service Charges">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Rs" ng-maxlength="4" ng-model="thingstodo_additional.servicecost">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">         
      <button class="button button-block button-balanced">{{(thingstodo|totalCost : type ) + thingstodo_additional.labourcost + thingstodo_additional.servicecost}}.00 RS</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <button class="button button-block button-dark" ng-click="collectData()">Confirm</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
$scope.rows = []; // rows array
$scope.counter = 5;
$scope.addRow = function() 
{
    $scope.rows.push($scope.counter);
    $scope.counter++;
}

$scope.deleteRow = function(index,rowContent) 
{   
    $scope.type = $scope.thingstodo[rowContent].cost;       
    $scope.rows.splice(index, 1);
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to move the maths into your controller:

```
<button class="button button-block button-balanced">{{(getTotalCost()}}.00 RS</button>

$scope.getTotalCost = function()
{
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach(function(value, key)
    {
        total += $scope.thingstodo[key].cost;
    });

    return total + $scope.thingstodo_additional.labourcost + $scope.thingstodo_additional.servicecost;
}
```

Or something very similar. Then add any filter / formatting of the number you want back in.

The method will be called just as often as an other change to the view.

Comment: How to call filter in this is deleteRow (I'm new to anugular js)

$scope.deleteRow = function(index,rowContent) 
{   
    $scope.type = $scope.thingstodo[rowContent].cost;       
    $scope.rows.splice(index, 1);
}

Comment: Sorry Gowri, I'm not sure what you're asking